# Using variable value in a lambda expression from another

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am currently practicing Akka actor. I am writing a code to read a very big and print the word count. In the given below code, the variable "fileCount" is in the first lambda expression and I am assigning some value to it. I want to use that value in the second lambda expression. Is it possible?

```
public class MainMaster extends AbstractActor{
    private long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    private int fileCount = 0;
    private int localCount = 0;

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(FileHashMap.class, f -> {
            System.out.println("\tCount \t||\tWords");
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
            fileCount = f.getFileHash().size()
            ActorRef master = this.getContext().actorOf(Props.create(Master.class, 10)
                                  .withRouter(new BalancingPool(fileCount);
            for(String file : f.getFileHash())
                master.tell(new FileManager(file), getSelf());
            })
            .match(String.class, s -> {
                localCount++;
                if(localCount >= fileCount) {
                    System.out.println(fileCount);
                    System.out.println("\n\n*******Time taken => "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)+"\n\n");

                }
            }
        ).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: `fileCount` is local variable in one lambda which cannot be used in another

Comment: Adding to the comment by @user7, variables used in lambdas that come from their outer scope must be effectively final, so you can't take `fileCount` out and mutate it

Comment: I want to use that fileCount in the other lambda expression. Is there any way to do that? @user7

Comment: @bumblebee: What's the output of the code?

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambdas can access instance variables. Since `fileCount`, in the posted code, isn't local it should be accessible from any lambda in the class.